# AWS EC2 -- create files with UserData script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to create an EC2 instance and have the `UserData` script create a file. When I `ssh` into the instance I see the S3 files but not `hello_world.txt` file. Do I need to add additional permissions?

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId='xxx',
        InstanceType='t2.micro',
        KeyName='xxx',
        SecurityGroups=['launch-wizard-12'],
        IamInstanceProfile={'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:instance-profile/data-processor'},
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        UserData='''#!/bin/bash
        aws s3 cp s3://terraflow-scripts /home/ubuntu/ --recursive # <-- this works
        echo this is a test > hello_world.txt # <------- this does not work
        '''
    )
```

Comment: You have given a relative path. Where are you checking for the file? I suspect it should be somewhere under /var/lib/cloud

Comment: You were right, I was able to fix the problem by providing an absolute path: `touch /home/ubuntu/test.txt`